# How do I restore previously removed android system app with adb?

Tags: android, adb, smartphone

I'm trying to remove some system apps from my android smartphone to debloat it. I use the following adb command: `adb shell pm uninstall package.to.remove`. But what if I will want to restore some of these apps? I can make a backup of the apk using `adb pull my.package path/i/want`. Then I can restore them using `adb shell pm install package.to.install`. I assume that the apps will be install as user app. So the questions are:

- Will the system apps work even if they are installed as an user app?
- Do I need to move the apks into the system partition?
- If I remove some system apps and then I update my smartphone, will it break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `pm uninstall` rather than `pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.package.name`,  I'm asuming that you have root access. If that's the case, then its better/safer to use `pm disable` because you could enable them anytime with `pm enable`. If you're talking about some "non-necessary" apps, but not a system component, then yes you can uninstall them. But be careful doing that. Do your research on the app before uninstalling them, because it could lead you into boot loop. Make sure to keep backups of your apps if possible, if something goes wrong, you could copy them back again to their directories.
If you have root privilege, then yes, copying the apps back to their original place will retain their functionality. But if you try installing them without root, just as a user or using `adb install`, the apps will no longer be a system app, and most probably will be useless since they are already in the system, just disabled/uninstalled for the current user. A factory reset will reset all the apps like before. Hope this helps (:

Comment: I don't have root because the bootloader is locked on my Huawei device. I'm not going to remove any system component but just the huawei mobile services (which to me are unnecessary because I use google play services) and some other preinstalled apps that I'm sure I won't need and I'm sure their removal won't compromise the device. But I always want to have a backup plan because you never know.

So without root access I can only restore them as user apps? Will they work anyway?

Comment: `pm uninstall` can only be used if you have root privilege. In your case, you might use `pm uninstall -k --user 0 package.name` since using direct pm uninstall will result in permission denial. I tried the same thing on my Mediatek phone, I did `adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.musicplayer` but before that, I pulled the apk on my storage. After deletion, I tried reinstalling the app, both manually and with adb install. It doesn't work. I also tried to uninstall the built in chrome, and installing a new Chrome version wont install at all.

Comment: Also, a factory reset will reset all the apps in their original place if you don't have root. Hence, if you do something out of ordinary, you can always reset your phone and everything will be back to factory version.

Answer (score 1):

These worked for me. I uninstalled **com.android.stk** which is the SIM Toolkit. I need this for mobile authentication in my country and couldn't get that working. It was removed using the program: *ADB AppControl*

Using [adb shell](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) I ran these 2 commands:

```
adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.android.stk i32 1 i32 0
adb shell pm install-existing com.android.stk
```

Which gave me the output:

> App installed for user 0

I didn't need root to run either of them. When you uninstall an app, you aren't actually removing it (unless you have root). You're just removing it for that user (disabling it). So thankfully I could get it back. I hope this helps someone else.